# Remove border-bottom for the cells in a specific column

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to remove the row seperator for a specific column. I tried overriding default styles by writing a scss mixin as shown below:

```
    .ag-theme-balham-custom {
       @include ag-theme-balham(
        (
          row-border-color: null,
        // row-border-color: blue,
        )
       );
     }
```

It is working but obviously it removes the seperator for all the grid rows. What I need to achieve is, if there are 10 columns, the row separator(bottom border) of 9th and 10th column's rows should be hidden by default and it should appear only when the header of corressponding column is hovered.

As highlighted in the image, the row seperator should be hidden for Test column and it should only appear when the Test column header is hovered.

[image: I am referring to the lines that are highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a cell-class rule to that specific column in your columnDefs i.e.

```
  {
    field: 'yourField',
    cellClassRules: { 'no-border-cell' },
  }
```

You can even apply class when your cell i.e.

```
cellClassRules: { 'no-border-cell': ({ data }) => data.fieldValue === 'a' }
```

For Row border you can use getRowStyle in your gridOptions i.e

```
gridOptions.getRowStyle(params) {
    if (params.data.myColumnToCheck === myValueToCheck) {
        return {'border': 'none'}
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Haseeb. Thanks for the answer. Adding cellClassRules didn't help. I have added an image in my question to just clarify what borders I am referring to.

Comment: Ok so the borders you are referring to are related to rows not columns (cells).

Comment: It worked for me, can you create an example of your code? or post the grid options you are using